# ERROR! Can't locate iPhoneSimulator SDK 9.0 RubyMotion

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, rubymotion

I have Xcode 7.1.1. I have already downloaded the iPhone 9.0 Simulator still I get this error.

```
❯ Rake
    ERROR! Can't locate iPhoneSimulator SDK 9.0 at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk'
```

I have also added sdk version 9.0 in my Rakefile.

```
❯ cat Rakefile
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
$:.unshift("/Library/RubyMotion/lib")
require 'motion/project/template/ios'

begin
  require 'bundler'
  Bundler.require
rescue LoadError
end

Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
  app.sdk_version = "9.0"
  app.deployment_target = "9.0"
  # Use `rake config' to see complete project settings.
  app.name = 'HelloMotion'
end
```

I have downloaded the iOS 9.0 simulator. You can see in the below screenshot.

[image: pic]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iOS 9.0 Simulator and iOS 9.0 Simulator SDK are two different things.

Legacy iOS Simulator SDKs no longer ship with the latest versions of Xcode.  To install an older Simulator SDK, take the `iPhoneSimulator.sdk` directory from an older version of Xcode (`Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/‌​iPhoneSimulator.sdk`), and copy it to your newer version.

For example, Xcode 7.0 comes with the 9.0 iOS Simulator SDK.  To install that in Xcode 7.1, take the directory:

```
Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk
```

Rename it from `iPhoneSimulator.sdk` to `iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk`.

Copy it to your Xcode 7 Simulator SDK directory:

```
Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs
```

Run `xcodebuild -showsdks` in your terminal and observe your new Simulator SDKs.

Comment: is there any way that I don't delete the new SDK and still access old SDK for building my RubyMotion project? By specifying some path or something. Because as far as I know this configuration will be messed up if I update Xcode

Comment: I don't use RubyMotion, so I can't answer the question.  It might be better to answer a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The command xcode-select provides the functionality you're looking for - i.e. to select between multiple installed versions of Xcode.